# Max length of traces / wires for MC680x0 relocator

Tags: cpu, motorola-68000, amiga-cdtv

What is the maximum length of a relocator traces or wires that will reliably send signals to Mother Board of a CDTV. I bought TF536, unfortunately due to miscommunication with the seller the card turned out to not fit the case at all. Effectively I have a useless $200 laying around and no purpose for it. Can I still salvage it?

[image: TF536]

Answer (score 2):

According to the project page on GitHub for the [Open68000Relocator](https://github.com/SukkoPera/Open68000Relocator) board:

```
The board has been tested and proved to be 
working perfectly with a TF530 card running
at 50 MHz.
```

So, if you can use the same swapping of the 68k orientation in the CDTV, then this re-locator would probably have a good chance of working. Likewise, some minor variation that does not introduce additional noise in the PCB would probably work too.

Bottom line is you'll have to try it out and see whether it works and whether it meets your own expectations for reliability.

Sometimes, in my experience, the most important factor is the mechanical stability of these socket extenders once they are installed in the Amiga. You may need to take some additional pains to ensure the board is well supported and won't simply wiggle loose. Using good quality mechanical pins/sockets can help with this, as well as installing standoffs to better support the board, if necessary.

Comment: I don't know about the CDTV specifically, but whenever I have had problems with things that plug into IC sockets, these problems have been mechanical.